# Code appears when clicking the inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox

This only happens to me in Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow PT-BR, including Meta.

With Google Chrome, I am not using an AdBlock. I am using an extension that blocks tracking/third party requests (DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials). I click inbox and this happens. If I disable the extension, the inbox returns to normal.

A video for reference:

[image]

[image: Inbox bug]

A zoomed-in view:

[image: Inbox bug up close]

Comment: Do you have any extensions / user scripts installed on your browser? What is the browser and its version that you are using? Can't reproduce this on Firefox 111.0 (Windows)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ok, i am not using an AdBlock, i am using an extension (DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials) that blocks tracking/third party requests. I deactivated it and now the inbox is normal. However, now i don't know if i should exclude the question.

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco I would just answer it, someone else is bound to run into this.

Comment: Yeah I have run into the same issue so would be nice to answer it @RenatoC.Francisco haha, I asked my Q on Meta.SE and got linked to this question: [Can see code when clicking on my notifications box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387793/1258746)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is related to the extension DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials. Having it enabled somehow leads to this issue.

Note that it is only a *visual bug*. While annoying it does not seem have impact on the operation on anything. The HTML for the inbox is (shortened)

```html
<li role="presentation"><!-- this is the icon of the inbox in the top bar-->
    <div class="topbar-dialog inbox-dialog dno" role="menu" style="display: none;">
        <!--this is the inbox that opens up -->
    </div>
    
    <script>
        if(StackExchange == null) {
            StackExchange = {};
        }
        if(StackExchange.settings == null) {
            StackExchange.settings = {};
        }
        if(StackExchange.settings.topBar == null) {
            StackExchange.settings.topBar = {};
        }
        StackExchange.settings.topBar.enableInboxManagement = true;
    </script>
</li>
```

When opening the dialog the `<div>` is shown by setting `style` to `display: block;` (done via jQuery's [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)).

With DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials for some reason the `.toggle()` is also applied to the `<script>` tag which sets its `style` property to `display: block;` which shows it - what you see in the top bar is the content of that tag. Closing the dialog sets the `style` to `display: none;` again.

I am not sure *why* or *how* DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials affects the behaviour here but so far I can see it is the source of the behaviour.

See [the answer by Kaiido here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387805) for more information on the technical problem that the extension introduces.

Comment: Han I was already half-way into [my answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387805/269001) when I saw yours here. I've been a bit father in the rabbit hole if you're interested ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the insight! I didn't have the time to dig deeper. This is useful information. What I did check is the issues in GitHub for DDGPE but I didn't see anything that seemed related. At least that was *before* I read your answer. I'll check now if it's reported as another kind of issue and I might raise a new issue if it's not reported yet.

Comment: @VLAZ I have reported the issue [here](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckgo-privacy-extension/issues/1819) thank you though, I asked the [Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387793/can-see-code-when-clicking-on-my-notifications-box) and got linked to this, thanks for the insight!