# Cookie banner keeps popping up

Tags: support, cookies

Until a few days ago, clicking the "Necessary cookies only" made the banner disappear as long as I kept my cookies (I delete them when I close Firefox, and I don't mind setting my preferences once per browser session).  This does not work any more, and the banner keeps popping up. Clicking "Accept all cookies" doesn't work either. When I click on "customize settings", nothing happens.

On [the DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange site, the functionality is still working as it should.

I am using Firefox 112.0.1 on [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) Linux 37.  This must have been broken by some recent Stack Overflow update.

This is *not* the same as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416632/how-do-i-make-stack-overflow-stop-asking-for-cookie-preferences): I delete my cookies at the end of each browser session, and I don't mind setting my preferences once per browser session. But I don't want the cookies banner to reappear upon reload if I set my preferences in that browser session.

Comment: Keeps reappearing for me, pretty much every second day. Been happening for a few years, on all SE sites, in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Possible MSE dupe: [How do I permanently set my cookie preferences?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387379/how-do-i-permanently-set-my-cookie-preferences)

Comment: @cocomac No, that's not the same. I clear my cookies when I close my browser, and I don't mind the banner reappearing whenever I start Firefox. But I would like to be able to get rid of it _for the duration of one browser session_, which does not work any more.

Comment: FF 112 did have an issue with Cookies and setting their expiration date. Is that fixed already in the minor release you have?

Comment: Apply the annoyance filters (specifically EasyList Cookies IIRC, though I don't remember exactly) in uBlock Origin. It makes the cookie dialog go away entirely. It won't fix the problem, but it means you don't have to be annoyed every time Stack breaks the dialog

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine or the browser dev breaks cookies :) There are always two sides to a coin.

Comment: @Gimby Sure, but one is significantly more likely to happen than the other

Comment: Related: *[How do I make Stack Overflow stop asking for cookie preferences?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416632/)*

Comment: I am experiencing this with FF 112.0.1 on Windows 10. It is not a problem on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ or https://english.stackexchange.com (for example).

Comment: This [Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424346/2310830) appears to have worked for me. I disabled "DuckDuckGo Security Essentials" extension of FF 112, then went to SO, selected my cookie option, now I am not getting a cookie dialog on each page and each page refresh. Re-enabled DDGo after doing this and still appear to have fixed it

Comment: @RiggsFolly That may  stop the cookie banner from showing up, but I'd like to only accept essential cokies. Ideally, Stackoverflow would store my cookie preferences with my profile and not ask me any more.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The option I picked was "Only Essential Cookies"

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right, that workaround seems to do the trick. I specifically excluded stackoverflow.com from the DuckDuckGo protected sites. Still, some recent change must have broken this. It used to work without such antics.

Comment: Agree, its a major pain and needs fixing properly. Unfortunately I dont know enough to be able to postulate such a fix @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: That recent change could be on your browser's side... Maybe it's now also clearing cookies when you close all the site's tabs, or something like that. I think it's very unlikely SE's changed how their cookies worked...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Stack Overflow stop asking for cookie preferences?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416632/how-do-i-make-stack-overflow-stop-asking-for-cookie-preferences)

Comment: @Cerbrus As I wrote in the question, the problem does not manifest on DBA Stackexchange. So it is not the browser's fault.

Comment: @Cerbrus So it is not a duplicate of the question you suggested.

Comment: This might be related to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423678/code-appears-when-clicking-the-inbox#comment950440_423678) for which some changes / exclusions were made in DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials: https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckgo-privacy-extension/issues/1819

Comment: Yea, so it's definitely not an SE issue...

Comment: @Cerbrus The proof that it is a SE problem is that it works with DBA SE, but recently stopped working with SO.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: That github issue Abdul linked states they have some exceptions in place for certain SE sites. Again, I think it's extremely unlikely SE would change anything about how cookie consent works on their sites. That's a pretty core feature that already works... No reason to mess with it. Even more proof that this is a client-side issue, is that there's plenty of browsers out there that don't have this problem.

Comment: No repro on Firefox 112.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 (yes, I know). With [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) (e.g., (by default) blocking JavaScript from *cookielaw.org* (probably not significant)).

Comment: I see the same behavior with Chrome. SO started asking me to accept cookies at EVERY visit. I haven't changed cookie settings in ages. This started like 2 weeks ago roughly.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Deactivating DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials for stackoverflow.com solved the issue for me although it might be not related to the mentioned issue. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hmm, this is happening for me on every page load today. Previously it was only popping up every 5-10 days. This will get annoying quickly

Comment: People seriously need to learn how to search for existing questions. There's so many duplicates of this now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is probably not a complete answer, but it shows possible causes and a remedy.

- The problem could be the web browser:

  My latest Firefox upgrade was not so long ago, and I have the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" installed. Disabling that extension makes the problem disappear. The problem may be related to code changes in "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials", since [similar problems](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckgo-privacy-extension/issues/1819) were caused by that extension.
- The problem may be a code change in Stack Overflow:

  What makes this theory likely is that the problem does not appear with other Stack Exchange sites.

At any rate, if you trust Stack Overflow, you can get rid of the problem like this:

- open "Add-ons and themes" in Firefox
- at the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials", click the three dots and select "Preferences"
- scroll down and select "Add unprotected site"
- add "stackoverflow.com"
- the next time the cookie banner pops up, configure your preferences, and it will leave you alone as long as you keep Stack Overflow's cookies

Comment: Alternatively, you can click on the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials icon in the tray of add-ons to the right of the URL box (assuming you have this tray active), then click the toggle switch next to 'Protections are on for this site'.