# Persistent cookies prompt

Tags: support

Every time I visit a page on SO. I get the "Your privacy" popup in the lower left corner. Even after I make a selection, it will reappear the next time I visit the site.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424347/238704), or something else? A screenshot wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yup, looks like my question is a dupe of that one.

Comment: What browser, incl. version? On what system, incl. version? Relevant plugins? Relevant browser configuration?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think the relevant part of that is I have DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials as mentioned in the comments to the dupe. It isn't the first time this plugin has caused problems with SO.